# SPServices to build data table with URL

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-2010, spservices

The problem is that I'm getting different results eachtime when I change the quotes. I have to use this method as downloading a `KML` file with other methods opens the KML in a new tab and displays the XML version when I want users to download it by clicking on the button.

I have the following code `'<td><input type="button" value="Download" onclick="window.location.href=\'http://myportal/download.aspx?SourceUrl=http://myportal/KML/'+ KMLName +'/></td>' +`

The output results is in consistent at best. Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

This was resolved by properly escaping the single quotes.